# Firing a function on link click (Seems to work, but not on a popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

Trying to fire a custom facebook pixel event clicking to an external link (So I can track the analytics of customers going to an external link).  I have a function that does work, and I have that attached to a normal link.

Works great on the normal website using `onclick="function();"` method, but I can't seem to get it working on a popup.  I don't have full ability on the popup plugin I am using to modify the HTML around the link, but I can implement Javascript / Jquery on start of the page.

Was hoping there may be an overall method so that all link clicks will fire the event, and it's applied to all links after a delay (giving time for the popup to load.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen for clicks on all buttons and `a` elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a, button").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", customEventHandler));
```